# How can I run systemsettings in super user mode in kde 4.3.4

Tags: linux, debian, kde, kde-4

I am trying to set up samba server on my box, and the easiest way seems to be to use the kde4 samba setting dialog. I need to run it as super user though. I tried

```
su -
systemsettings
```

but the window doesn't seem to appear on the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using krunner (alt+f2) and type:

> kdesu systemsettings

should work if you know the root password...

Comment: Kdesu is not always present, execute: kdesudo systemsettings

Comment: This  no longer works (plasma 5.9) kdesu gives error.